# MySQL Server cannot start

Tags: mysql, cmd, sqlcmd

Whenever I try to start mysql server using this command,

```
C:\> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld"
```

It returns me this error and server won't start

```
2022-01-14T04:31:15.902534Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld (mysqld 8.0.27) starting as process 3380
2022-01-14T04:31:15.908243Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2022-01-14T04:31:15.908376Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2022-01-14T04:31:15.908671Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013276] [Server] Failed to set datadir to 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\' (OS errno: 2 - No such file or directory)
2022-01-14T04:31:15.909424Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-01-14T04:31:15.909709Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.27)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

I really appreciate your help thanks.

Comment: Have you investigated this part of the message: `(OS errno: 2 - No such file or directory)`? What did you find?

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to Services tab on your windows and check whether MySQL running or not.
2.Adding MySQL to path,

- Open "Edit system variables".
- Click on "Environment variables"
- Click on "Path" and click on "Edit"
- Click on "New" and paste your MySQL path.
  (C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin)
  3.From doing above scenarios you don't need to call your MySQL path every time you want to run MySQL using command line.
  4.Now open command line and type this (Here -u is username and -p is password),

  - mysql -u root -p (After typing hit enter).
  - It will ask for your password, if you have no password just hit enter